# c++ how to get address of an object in a vector from iterator

Tags: c++

I have a vector vec that contains objects Order (not pointers to the objects)

Now I need to find a certain object in the container and manipulate it

```
for ( auto it = vec.begin(); it !=  vec.end(); ++it ) {

    Order *p_o = it; // ERROR HERE
    if ( p_o->id_ == id ) { p_o->size_ -= reduce_amount; }

}


error: C2440: 'initializing': cannot convert from 'std::_Vector_iterator<std::_Vector_val<std::_Simple_types<Order>>>' to 'Order *'
```

How can I get the the address of the object the iterator hold

I tried both

```
it.pointer
it.reference
```

but that yields

```
C:\CPP\Simulator\Venue\venue.cpp:88: error: C2274: 'function-style cast': illegal as right side of '.' operator
```

Comment: Maybe try `it->pointer`?

Comment: `it !=  vec` should be `it !=  vec.end()` Also why do you want to retrieve a pointer? Just access `Order` by reference.

Comment: Your condition for the loop exit is wrong. It should be `it !=  vec.end()`. You can try `p_o = &*it`.

Comment: Why not just `for (auto& x : vec) { if (x.id_ == id) x.size -= reduce_amount; }`. I'd also reconsider whether using a `map` or `unordered_map` keyed on `id` would make more sense as well rather than a vector. Just something to think about.

Comment: @ ForceBru. that did not work, but thanks for highlighting the ->
It seems it->size_ -= reduce_amount works fine

Comment: @WhozCraig why? because I didnt know that this exists. But it looks quite neat and I am happy to use that. That discovery is more than I was hoping to learn from that question

Comment: @chrise Post a [MCVE] that actually reproduces your problem please. Your edit is pretty futile.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Iterators *model* pointers, but aren't necessarily pointers themselves. So just dereference it, and if you really need to point at the object, take the address of that:

```
auto& my_ref_to_the_object = *iter;
auto* my_ptr_to_the_object = &my_ref_to_the_object;
```

Your code doesn't seem like you need a real pointer to the object at all:

```
for (auto it = vec.begin(); it !=  vec.end(); ++it) {
    Order& p_o = *it;
    if (p_o.id_ == id) {
        p_o.size_ -= reduce_amount;
    }
}
```

Or even simpler:

```
for (Order& p_o : vec) {
    if (p_o.id_ == id) {
        p_o.size_ -= reduce_amount;
    }
}
```

Comment: I do quite like the simpler version. Is that a shortcut way of invoking an iterator.. that is, is that implementation equally fast/efficient?

Comment: @chrise: It's a "range-based for loop", and is basically syntactic sugar for an iterator-based for loop. Don't worry about speed. If it's cleaner, it's the better choice. Your program doesn't need to be as fast as possible, it just needs to be fast enough. So choose the clean code while you can, and once the program is too slow you'll profile it to find out where the slowness is. It's not going to be in the way you do for loops, but the contents within.